Fetch get запрос
Итак товарищи, для моего проекта нужно с помощью этой кнопки перейти к оформлению заказа.
  <CardActions>

Перейти к оформлению

По идее, должен срабатывать путь: http://localhost:8080/card/get?id=....
И переход на следующую страницу с информацией о заказе или продукте.
 const handleClickAddBook=(e)=> {
    e.preventDefault()
    const card ={uuid,number}
    console.log(card)
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/card/get?id=",{
        method:"GET",
        headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"},
    })
}

Я новичок в JS и не понимаю, как это сделать. Конкретно не могу понять вот что: как в fetch запрос вставить id заказа/продукта.

Прошу прощения, первый раз оставляю вопрос. Кнопка выглядит так -                         Перейти к оформлению


как в fetch запрос вставить id заказа/продукта.

Например вот так
const handleClickAddBook=(e)=> {
    e.preventDefault()
    const card ={uuid,number}
    console.log(card)
    const url = new URL('http://localhost:8080/card/get');
    url.search = new URLSearchParams(card);
    fetch(url,{
        method:"GET",
        headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"},
    })
}

